# Python Module not found error - not getting fixed

Tags: python

So I am pretty new with Python. I've been working on running with a code similar to one I hope to build myself (so a reference code). Aside from some bugs I need to work out with invalid syntax, all seems to work except for one issue with one particular `.py` file I have.

My structure is this:

```
MoodForecasting -> eval -> nsga_two.py
```

I do have `_init_.py` in eval folder though, so I'm not sure why this block of code isn't working.

I am trying to load one particular fucntion from it, so the structure should look like this

```
from nsga_two import PatientProblem
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nsga_two'`.

I checked `nsga_two.py` itself and found that it couldn't load `inspyred`. I went in and was able to fix this. So, `nsga_two.py` runs fine on its own. However, I cannot import it into the main script I will be working with.

Some extra details: I am working with the IDE `Spyder` with Python Custom Version 3.7.9.

I'm not sure if it is an issue with Spyder or just how I am loading in my working directory. (Most of my coding experience is in MatLab and R so having an IDE similar to RStudio and MatLab is the reason I chose to work in Spyder)

Edit:
I got a syntax error when using `from eval import nsga_two.PatientProblem`. Python didn't like the period. So, I instead tried it with no period. I got the `error cannot import name 'nsga_twoPatientProblem' from 'eval' (C:\Users\name\Desktop\MoodForecasting-master\MoodForecasting-master\eval\__init__.py)`. I don't know why. But doing `from eval import nsga_two` works. `nsga_two.py` only consists of `PatientProblem`. This solve should be ok for this purpose. I'm just not sure why this could be happening.

Comment: did you try `from eval import ngsa_two.PatientProblem` (although assuming 'eval' is directory I strongly suggest change it to something more innocuous).

Comment: Thanks. That kind of works. I got a syntax error when using ```from eval import ngsa_two.PatientProblem```. Python didn't like the period. So, I instead tried it with no period. I got the error ```cannot import name 'nsga_twoPatientProblem' from 'eval' (C:\Users\name\Desktop\MoodForecasting-master\MoodForecasting-master\eval\__init__.py)```. I don't know why. But doing ```from eval import ngsa_two``` works. ```ngsa_two.py``` only consists of ```PatientProblem```. So this should be ok for this purpose. Like I said, this is a reference code so I haven't named any of these folders but will change

Comment: `nsga_two` or `ngsa_two` is the correct module name? Are you importing with wrong name which raise the error?  Where is your main script located?

Comment: Sorry, typos throughout I just noticed. It should be ```nsga_two```. The main script is located in a folder called MoodForecasting which contains other folders such as eval which have other ```.py``` files in them.

Comment: If `from eval import ngsa_two` works then what you want is `from eval.ngsa_two import PatientProblem`. You will want to read up on the syntax and semantics of the Python `import` statement. The suggestion in the first comment is not and has never been syntactically valid in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your structure is like:

```
MoodForecasting-master/
    main.py
    eval/
        __init__.py
        nsga_two.py
```

When you run the main script to import something, the directory of that script is added to the module search path `sys.path`, `.../MoodForecasting-master/` in this case. `from nsga_two import PatientProblem` raised `ModuleNotFoundError` because `nsga_two.py` is not in that directory.

As Iguananaut said, `from eval import nsga_two.PatientProblem` in the first comment has never been a valid statement. The valid ways of doing so are:

1. import by `from eval import nsga_two` and use as `nsga_two.PatientProblem()`.
2. import by `from eval.nsga_two import PatientProblem` and use as `PatientProblem()` directly.

Module search starts from `.../MoodForecasting-master/`, first option go to `.../MoodForecasting-master/eval/` to find `nsga_two.py`, second option go to `.../MoodForecasting-master/eval/nsga.py` to find attribute named `PatientProblem`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be:

from package.module import function

so:

from eval.nsga_two import PatientProblem